# Why does Setq work but not let?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm following the syntax as it is in my book "The land of lisp" and the let version only returns nil when passed *string*. Whereas the "setq" version returns the reversed version of *string*.

```
(defparameter *string* "a b c")
(defun reverse-string (string)
    (let (reversed (string))))

(defun setq-reverse-string (string)
    (setq reversed (reverse string)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of `LET` is:

```
(LET ((var1 val1)
      (var2 val2)
      ...)
  body)
```

In place of `(varN valN)` you can just put `varN`, which is shorthand for `(varN nil)`. You can also omit `valN`, in which case it defaults to `nil`.

So your code is equivalent to:

```
(defun reverse-string (string)
  (let ((reversed nil)
        (string nil))))
```

You're missing a level of parentheses to do what you want:

```
(defun reverse-string (string)
  (let ((reversed (string)))))
```

You're also missing the call to `reverse`, and returning the variable

```
(defun reverse-string (string)
  (let ((reversed (reverse string)))
    reversed))
```

Comment: Haha, thanks man, I thought that it only required let to have a double (( if defining more than one variable, and thanks for pointing the bit about missing "reverse" out, I had that in my original but I've edited it so many times I must have missed it out. I appreciate the really quick response.

Comment: As far as it could tell, you were defining two variables: `reversed` and `string`. How could it tell that you meant to define only one variable?

Comment: You couldn't it was my mistake, not yours :) Thanks for the help so quickly!